# Why is strncmp not comparing? Socket programing C

Tags: c, strncmp

I'm trying to parse the received data from a client in a server. The server have to send back a message according to what the client sent before. But I can not make the strncmp function compare the strings. It always get to the else and my server close the conection. Also my client stays connected and print in screen the option I typed.

Please need help to understand what is wrong!

Thanks!

> Incorrect Inputclose error: Bad file descriptor
>
> Program exited with code 01.

```
void
result(int sockfd)
{
    ssize_t     n;
    char        buf[MAXLINE];
    int         temp;
    time_t      ticks;
    int         i;
again:
    while ((n =read(sockfd, buf, 15)> 0))
    {
     buf[n] = '\0';
     printf("Message Recieved:%s\n",buf);
     srand (time(NULL));
     temp = rand() % 15+1;
     printf("Ramdom es %i\n",temp);

     if ((strncmp (buf,"A",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"a",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You chose option A -%i times on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
     }
     if ((strncmp (buf,"B",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"b",1) == 0))
     {
      snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You chose option B -%i times on on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
      Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Incorrect Input");
       Close(sockfd);
       break;
     }  
    }
    if (n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
    goto again;
    else if (n < 0)
        err_sys("read error");
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t           len;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char                buff[MAXLINE];
    /*char                message[MAXLINE];*/
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);/*----------------------------------------------------*/
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(5678); 

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    printf("EDMTS is running on 129.128.4.80, listening on port 5678\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...Press Ctrl+C to end server\n");

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);

        /*Client connects to server*/
        printf("\n");
        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));

           result(connfd);
               Close(connfd);

    }
}
```

Comment: At least one problem is that your program closes the socket twice.

Comment: Socket data probably isn't null terminated.

Comment: When the `printf` statement shows the message received, what does it say?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It looks like the first thing he does is null terminate it in his while loop.

Comment: Can you print the output please? `read` returns "the number of bytes read". So, maybe you want `buf[n-1] = '\0';`?

Comment: I got rid of `goto` the same day I through my BBC computer into the skip. Perhaps you should do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little logic

```
 if ((strncmp (buf,"B",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"b",1) == 0))
 {
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You chose option B -%i times on on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
  Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
 }
 else
 {
   printf("Incorrect Input");
   Close(sockfd);
   break;
 }
```

Is where the else lies.

I.e.

it gets run when after it is hits this:

```
 if ((strncmp (buf,"A",1) == 0) || (strncmp (buf,"a",1) == 0))
 {
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "You chose option A -%i times on %.24s\r\n", temp,ctime(&ticks));
  Writen(sockfd, buf, n);
 }
```

BTW use `toupper` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/

i.e.

```
 if ('B' == toupper(buf[0]) ...
```

Just add another ELSE!

Comment: @Eric Urban...it never gets to the snprintf.

Comment: @crony...(gdb) p buf
$1 = "c", '\0' <repeats 2027 times>, "\203\037��", '\0' <repeats 12 times>, "H�\215�H�\215�d�\215��O��#\204��\000\000\000\000��\215��\207����\215�#\204��", '\0' <repeats 20 times>, "������������\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000�\237��", '\0' <repeats 16 times>, "H�\215�", '\0' <repeats 20 times>, "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\204�\215�", '\0' <repeats 36 times>, "����\t\000\000\000#\204��\030\204��\000\000\000\000H�\215�\003", '\0' <repeats 19 times>, "\n\000\000\000G�\215�", '\0' <repeats 40 times>, " ", '\0' <repeats 11 times>...
(gdb) p temp
$2 = 14

Comment: @netfreak- Eh? Why in gibberish but then I was assuming that this MB was English

Comment: Thank you! I was missing a else. Now the server does not get into any if...can someone help me? Y use printf to see the process and if generates the random number and stays there waiting. Can someone tell me why?